# Invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I can not put the column `JobDeliveryDateIn` in `GROUP BY` clause, SQL Server 2012, solution for this problem please.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    StockCode,
    CASE 
       WHEN JobDeliveryDate < GETDATE() 
          THEN SUM(QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) 
          ELSE SUM(0) 
    END AS Vencido,
    CASE 
       WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= GETDATE() AND JobDeliveryDate < (GETDATE() + 5) 
          THEN SUM(QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) 
          ELSE SUM(0) 
    END AS Semana1, 
    CASE 
       WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= (GETDATE() + 5) AND JobDeliveryDate < (GETDATE() + 15) 
          THEN SUM(QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) 
          ELSE SUM(0) 
    END AS Semana2,
    CASE 
       WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= (GETDATE() + 15) 
          THEN SUM(QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) 
          ELSE SUM(0) 
    END AS Futuro
FROM
    SysproManutesa.dbo.WipMaster
WHERE     
    (Complete = 'N') AND (QtyManufactured < QtyToMake)
GROUP BY 
    StockCode
ORDER BY 
    StockCode
```

Comment: Please read the manual on how group by works, you cannot do what you are doing because you do not fully understand group by.  We don't really appreciate questions that simply show code and ask us to fix it.  You should spend some time understanding why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Why top 100 percent?

Comment: the code does not work because JobDeliveryDate field data are in the air , when GROUP -BY eliminates repeated StockCode field ,  is redundancy , seeking a solution to that problem please

Comment: @SeanLange - That means it is part of a view.  Some strange requirement of sql-server.

Comment: @Hogan I kind of figured it was part of a view. You have to do that when adding an order by to a view. The problem is that the order by will be ignored when executing a query. Consider a query with two views each with an order by...which one wins??? The requirement is a hold over from sql 2000 and earlier when the engine would actually honor the order by in the first view listed in a query. Today the syntax requirement is still there but the logic in the engine ignores the order by.

Comment: @SeanLange - yes all such things stopped mattering after the introduction of windowing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `error message` said, you can only use those column whose are in the `group by` and `Aggregate Functions` in the `select list`. (Check Aggregate Functions [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)). As `Case When` is not `aggregate function`, `SQL SERVER` give you the error message. You need to change your query like below:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    StockCode,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate < GETDATE() 
                 THEN (QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) 
             ELSE 0 END) AS Vencido,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= GETDATE() AND JobDeliveryDate < (GETDATE() + 5) 
                 THEN QtyToMake - QtyManufactured 
             ELSE 0 END) AS Semana1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= (GETDATE() + 5) AND JobDeliveryDate < (GETDATE() + 15) 
                 THEN QtyToMake - QtyManufactured
             ELSE 0 END) AS Semana2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate >= (GETDATE() + 15) 
                THEN QtyToMake - QtyManufactured 
             ELSE 0 END) AS Futuro
FROM SysproManutesa.dbo.WipMaster
WHERE (Complete = 'N') AND (QtyManufactured < QtyToMake)
GROUP BY StockCode
ORDER BY StockCode
```

Comment: hello,  no problem with the JobDeliveryDate field type dateTime  with sum

Comment: @MahediSabuj- thanks for you help I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the sums in the case statement but you can have the case statements in the sum... refactor statements like this:

```
CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate < GETDATE() THEN SUM(QtyToMake - QtyManufactured) ELSE SUM(0) END AS Vencido,
```

to this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN JobDeliveryDate < GETDATE() THEN QtyToMake - QtyManufactured ELSE 0 END) AS Vencido,
```

Once you have done it a few times it will be clear why this works.

Comment: hello, no problem with the JobDeliveryDate field type dateTime with sum

Comment: @OmarFrancoAlvarez -- you are wrong.  You have a problem.  This is why you are getting an error message.

Comment: @Hogan-- thanks for you help I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this problem and the way I have done it is to wrap the inner in a common table expression. I don't want to post my exact code but is goes something like this:

With CTE as (select case when [Type] like '%A%' or [Type] like '%b%' then null else ExpDate end as  ExpDate, Amount from table)
select Expdate, sum(amount) from CTE group by Expdate

Gets around having views referencing other views which was my problem. Probably fine for most things, just beware of performance on big tables and data sets as I am not sure how CTEs use memory / disk / tempdb.